# Difference between new calls in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between `new functionName()` and `new functionName` in JavaScript?

Comment: None, brackets are optional if there are no arguments.

Comment: @gurvinder372 Is there not any difference at any use case?

Comment: *"if there are no arguments"*

Comment: @meskobalazs i got that. just wanted to confirm no other meaning present for that piece of code